# How can i compute half edges given an array of vertices and an array of indices?

Tags: data-structures, graph, graphics, mesh

If i have the following:

- array of vertices: contains vertices of a mesh with x,y,z values.
- array of indices: contains the indices which links together vertices

How can i compute the directed half edges ?

Comment: Do you mean building the data structure? Or just creating a list of directed edges?

Comment: @Makogan i need to build an array which contains each vertex with an arbitrary directed edge alongside it. Also need to build another array which contains the pairs of directed edges.

Comment: ok you are literally building a half edge data structure.

Answer (score 1):

To build the half edge data structure, the easiest method I know is to use maps.

Each vertex id is its index in the array, each half edge's id is the ORDERED pair of the vertices that make up that edge.

I will assume you are dealing with triangle meshes only, it can be generalized for polygonal faces but for explanation’s sake it keeps it simpler.

- Iterate your index array 3 by 3 (3 indices make up a face.)
- Assume i,j,k are the 3 indices you just grabbed. Then your 3 half edges are (i,j); (j,k); (k,i).
- Check the map, if the permutation (e.g. k,j) of a half edge is already in the map, that's the pair of the edge. Otherwise we have not found the edge.
- If the pair exists, allocate the newly found edge besides the first.
- Otherwise allocate 2 slots and store the new edge on the first position. (When you alter find the pair, it will be allocated on the other slot).

If you want an implementation reference:
https://gitlab.com/Makogan/vkengine/-/blob/master/Src/Engine/MasterEngine/Geometry/HMesh.hpp